# More advice than asked for

Tags: discussion

Should we give as much advice as possible about the piece of text presented in the question? Sometimes a piece of text quoted has several issues, but the asker only wants advice on one bit of the text. Should we overreach and give as much help as possible, or only talk about the topic they’ve asked for help with?

Also, since it seems superfluous to ask this in another question because it fits under the same topic: should we correct the (grammatical) content of a user’s post that doesn’t have to do with the question in our answers as well?

It seems like we should, so as to provide the best possible support for those learning English... but it does seem to overreach.

TL;DR: How pedantic should we be, and how helpful is too helpful?